# How to get moment from angular momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, torque

I have a mass spinning while attached to a string as shown in the diagram:

[image]

I can calculate the angular momentum of the mass as I know it's shape and rate of rotation (in deg/s). I want to calculate the shear stress in the 'string' I'm going to use this equation to do so:

[image]

I'm unsure how to calculate the torque? I realise the angular moment is measured in N.m.s and torque is measured in N.m, so in theory if I divide by time this should give me a torque, but I'm unsure what time I need to divide by!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to assume a defined motion, where $\theta(t)$ is known. If the mass was spinning with a constant rate there would be no torque needed. The basic equation of motion is $$T = I_{zz} \ddot{\theta}$$ where $I_{zz}=\int r^2 {\rm d}m$ is the *mass* moment of inertia about *z*.

That internal torque is the translated into shear stress with $$\tau = \frac{T R}{J_T}$$ where $J_T=\int r^2 {\rm d}A$ is the polar area moment

For cylindrical shape the above comes out to be $$\tau = \frac{m}{\pi R} \ddot{\theta}$$

Comment: Thanks! How would I calculate the second derivative of theta here? I have the rotational stiffness of the string (k). But I'm unsure how to apply this.

Comment: You never mentioned in the question that the body is rotating with simple harmonic motion. Thats an important detail. If you know the angular amplitude $\Theta$ then $${\rm max}(\ddot{\theta}) = \Theta \omega^2$$

Comment: All I know is the mass, and shape of the mass, the material of the string (and any constant values that come with), and the initial rate of rotation.

Comment: I've calculated the rotational stiffness of the string and the moment of inertia of the mass

Comment: The rotational stiffness is then $k = J_T \omega^2$ which is used to find the period of oscillation $t_{cycle}$ and $\omega = \frac{2 \pi}{t_{cycle}} $

Comment: Can I assume the deceleration of the rotation of the mass is linear? If so I can work out the rate of acceleration from the Tcycle now right?

Comment: Also what's the w (omega) value here? I can calculate it from sqrt(Jt/k), but what is the value? I assume Jt is the polar moment of inertia

Comment: I've followed through the logic here, but it ends up not using the mass of the object. How can this be correct?

Comment: The mass in included in $I_{zz}$. You have to use one or the other. Correction from before, $k= I_{zz} \omega^2$

Comment: Where Izz is the moment of inertia? That makes sense now! Thanks